# Catalyst voting app fund 6 waiting for update, current version can not vote

Tags: voting

I can not vote for fund 6 currently because if I start android catalyst voting app, it says there is an update version under construction I have to wait on before I can vote. so my question is: when will this update be available? time is running out, I think voting on fund 6 runs out soon. who can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Catalyst Fund 6 is not in the voting phase, it starts on 7th of October.

Check [Project Catalyst FAQ](https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/900006490763-Project-Catalyst-FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst voting is a two-step process.

- Register in the wallet and generate a QR Code
- Scan the QR code in the "voting app"

For the fund 6, the voting will start on 7 Oct 2021 [IOHK BLog](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/08/13/project-catalyst-fund-6-our-biggest-boldest-and-best-cardano-community-innovation-fund-yet/). The app is custom and will have the proposals being put on the vote, therefore it is likely the app may not be available until the proposals are finalized. The registration is a once in a "wallet lifetime" process. You will be able to reuse the QR code for every fund.